# How to reference a parent JavaScript function in a nested IIFE module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

Take the following code below... In the `setTimeout` anonymous function, what is the correct way to reference the `alert.hide()` method? Is it correct to just write out the whole call as `admin.alert.hide();`? or Is there a better way to reference `admin` without having to call it directly?

```
var admin = (function(jQuery, window, document, undefined) {
    return {
        loader : (function(admin) {
            var fade = 75;
            var loader = '#loader';
            return {
                show : function () {
                    jQuery(loader).stop().fadeIn(fade);
                },
                hide : function() {
                    jQuery(loader).stop().fadeOut(fade);
                }
            }
        })(),
        alert : (function() {
            var timeout;
            var fade = 500;
            var milliseconds = 1000;
            var alert = '#alert';
            return {
                timeout : timeout,
                show : function(message) {
                    jQuery(alert).find('p').text(message);
                    jQuery(alert).stop().fadeIn(fade);
                    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
                    this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {  }, milliseconds);
                },
                hide : function() {
                    jQuery(alert).stop().fadeOut(fade);
                }
            }
        })()
    }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
return 
{
    timeout : timeout,
    show : function(message) 
    {
        jQuery(alert).find('p').text(message);
        jQuery(alert).stop().fadeIn(fade);
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout((function() { this.hide(); }).bind(this), milliseconds);
    },
    hide : function() 
    {
        jQuery(alert).stop().fadeOut(fade);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works... is "bind" a prototype method?

Comment: @AndrewB Yeah, it's a prototype function from Function class.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind